# Getting file url after upload amazon s3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I need to get file url after upload the file to amazons3 server.
Here is my upload code.
How to return amazons3 path ?

```cs
public static bool UploadToS3(string bucketName, string bucketFilePath, Byte[] localPath)
{
    var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(Config.EmailServer.AwsAccessKey, Config.EmailServer.AwsSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = bucketFilePath,
        InputStream = new MemoryStream(localPath),
        AutoCloseStream = true,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
        StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy                
    };
    
    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What are 'PutObjectRequest' and 'PutObjectResponse'? Are they components of the Amazon S3 library?

Comment: You mean the external URL for your object?  You don't really need to get it. It's known:  https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/mykey .  If you want the internal for AWS it's s3://<mybucket>/mykey

Answer (score 12):

Simply you can generate download expiry link after upload completed.

example:

```
var expiryUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
                           .WithBucketName(BucketName)
                           .WithKey(Key)
                           .WithExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));

string url = _amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(expiryUrlRequest);
```

Comment: There is a way to get it from response object?

Comment: @ricardofranca There's no need to. The request only requires the bucket name and key, which you should have anyway if you just wrote a file to that bucket name and key.

Comment: @ricardofranca It's depend on the ACL policy of the uploaded object. If you set it to be public(Any body can access it without credential) then you don't need to create PreSignedURL and you can build the URL using the bucket name and the object key.

Comment: maximum expiry 604800 secounds.

Answer (score 5):

Try this method

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
request.BucketName = "my-bucket-name";
request.Key        = "secret_plans.txt";
request.Expires    = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
request.Protocol   = Protocol.HTTP;
string url = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
Console.WriteLine(url);
```